# How would you query a cumulative sum over x amount of days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the cumulative sum of sessions of a link for its first 3 days. I tried this but it doesn't seem to take the date clause into account:

```
    select
        date,
        link,
        sum(sessions) as sessions
            from ga
            where date <= date+interval 3 day
            group by link
```

But if I manually enter a date, it seems to work. Why is it not seeing date+interval 3 day as a proper date...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Date is a column, not a value, you need to provide a specific date entry. Also "between" is a better keyword to use in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `date` column in `GROUP BY` clause. Also, avoid using column name as `date`. It will create confusion.

Try below query :

```
select date_column,
        link,
        sum(sessions) as sessions
            from ga
            where date_column BETWEEN CURDATE()-3 AND CURDATE()
            group by link, date_column
```

Comment: I can't use current date though, each link will have its own start date in the date column, I just need it to look between each link's start date and 3 days after that start date. Does that make sense? I'm a newbie to all this so let me know if I'm not being clear enough. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: You mean to say.. you are trying to get link between two dates right ? start date and start date +3 days. ? Also, do share your table design and point out which column are you trying to compare